# Force Window command line use specific Network Adapter

Tags: git, networking, command-line, window

I have two network adapters, each connect to different network.
I have two git repository too, When I push my commit to one repo, something like

> git push -u origin developer

I have to disable other network adapter

[image]

Is there a way to run git or command line bind to specific network adapter not need disable network adapter, something like `git remote -v --network 10.1.2.3` ?

Comment: No. This must be resolved at the network routing level.

Comment: Oh, thank you. So, I have to write a command to change the network routing level then use git. Do you know the command to change the network routing level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is not supported by Git itself, as commented, you would need to use the [`netsh` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts) in order to disable/enable a [network adapter from command line](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-or-disable-wi-fi-and-ethernet-network-adapters-windows-10#manage_network_adapter_cmd)

You can see one example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14071803/6309) or in [this script](https://superuser.com/a/1248475/141):

```sh
@netsh interface set interface name="LAN1" admin=disabled
@netsh interface set interface name="LAN0" admin=Enabled
```

The idea for this script would be to detect which one is enabled and disabling it, enabling the other: the script would act as a switch and could be called as part of a git alias.